# How does hasNextInt actually works? (java)

Tags: java, input

I'm trying to build a pyramid as tall as indicated by the user. If I use the code below, it would tell me I didn't introduce an Integer btw 1-20...
commenting the *if (scan.hasNextInt*...) makes the code work, as long as I don't insert a number < 1.

Am I using *hasNextInt()* properly?

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
int rows = 0, i=1, j=0;

    //Asking for the Input
System.out.println("How many rows should the pyramid have?\n"+
                    "(Insert an Integer btw 1-20)");

    //Checking if there's an Input
if (scan.hasNextInt() && rows>0 && rows<=20)
    rows = scan.nextInt();
else System.out.println("Not an Integer btw 1-20 inserted");

    //Building the pyramid
while (i<=rows){
    while (j<i){System.out.print("*");j++;}
    System.out.println();
    i++;j=0;
}

scan.close(); //closing scan
}
```

Comment: I think here is the issue `if (scan.hasNextInt() && rows>0 && rows<=20)` initially rows =0. You can try `if (scan.hasNextInt() )` and check the value is between o and 20 later

Comment: I remember this exercise from 1st year Java programming ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you have it's that `rows` variable it's equals to `0` so it doesn't enter to the `if` statement.

```
if (scan.hasNextInt() && rows>0 && rows<=20) //Here rows it's equals to 0
    rows = scan.nextInt();
else System.out.println("Not an Integer btw 1-20 inserted");
```

You have to modify `rows` variable before enter to the `if`, if not, it always will display the message `"Not an Integer btw 1-20 inserted"`.

---

Try doing:

```
if (scan.hasNextInt())

    do{
       rows = scan.nextInt();
    while(rows>0 && rows<=20);

else System.out.println("There is no integer");
```

if you want that the user mandatorily enter an `int` between these two numbers. If not, you can replace the `do-while` loop by an `if` statement.

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Comment: Oh my gosh... How did you get it so fast! now works tight :)

Answer (score 1):

First you do:

```
int rows = 0
```

then

```
if (scan.hasNextInt() && rows>0 && rows<=20)
```

It can't ever be true as you only change the value of rows after the check. Either change the condition or the initial value of rows.

If you want to make sure the integer the user enters if in a certain interval you should use a do...while loop or something similar and prompt the user to enter a number again if it's not in the allowed interval.

Something like this:

```
do {
    //Asking for the Input
    System.out.println("How many rows should the pyramid have?\n"+
    "(Insert an Integer btw 1-20)");

    //Checking if there's an Input
    if (scan.hasNextInt()) {
        rows = scan.nextInt();
        if (rows > 0 && rows <= 20)
            break;  // leave the loop and continue
        else
            System.out.println("Not an Integer btw 1-20 inserted");
    }
} while (true); // loop forever.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the issue

`if (scan.hasNextInt() && rows>0 && rows<=20)`

initially `rows =0`.

You can try `if (scan.hasNextInt() )` and check the value is between o and 20 later

Answer (score 1):

In your 'IF' condition,

```
row > 0
```

is never going to be true because you have initialized it to 0 at the beginning and its value is never changed. 
I don't think you will need to add checks for rows variable in that IF condition. Instead, you can simply use,

```
if (scan.hasNextInt())
```